# #if #endif preprocessing Directive, PortAudio

Tags: c, sockets, portaudio, preprocessor-directive

I understand the basics to the #if #endif preprocessor directives in C, in that depending which expression evaluates to be true, the proceeding code within the #if  will be compiled, however I'm currently learning portaudio(I'm making a VOIP app for school) and I'm looking over some of their examples and I've become confused over a small section

```
/* Select sample format. */
#if 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0.0f)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%.8f"
#elif 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt16
typedef short SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#elif 0
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt8
typedef char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#else
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paUInt8
typedef unsigned char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (128)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#endif
```

the first question that comes to mind is

```
#if 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0.0f)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%.8f"
#elif 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt16
typedef short SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
```

wont the #elif 1 always be skipped because if somehow #if 1 (#if true) evaluates to false, wont #elif 1 also evaluate to false?

question 2 
isn't 1 evaluate to true and 0 to false? so wont #elif 0 always evaluate to false? i.e it doesn't really matter?

question 3
I'm going to be sending these samples over a socket, is skipping this preprocessor directive and just working with the code

```
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt8
typedef char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
```

or

```
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paUInt8
typedef unsigned char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (128)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#endif
```

Would that be beter so as my SAMPLE_TYPE/SAMPLE can be treated as an array of characters/ Unsigned Characters (not having to convert floats to chars and then back again) for writing/reading from the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to understand is between a sequence of #if / #elif / #else, only one condition will be selected:

`#if` is selected here:

```
#if 1
// only this one will be selected
#elif 1
#else
#endif
```

`#elif` is selected here:

```
#if 0
#elif 1
// only this one will be selected
#else
#endif
```

`#else` is selected here:

```
#if 0
#elif 0
#else
// only this one will be selected
#endif
```

Comment: I got that part I assumed it worked like a if statement in java/c/c++ etc. What I'm wondering is wont the #if 1 always be evaluated/compiled as it's essentially #if true? then the rest of them are thrown out?

Comment: Of course it will be always evaluated, the programmer probably did it that way so he could change these constants to select different conditions.

Comment: I gotcha that's what I was thinking, the #elif 1 just got me wondering why on earth there would be 2 ones and I made it out to be more complicated that it really had to be Thanks a lot! last question I'm working with sockets should I be using the Char/Unsigned Char data types (PortAudio not sure if you are familiar, will allocate memory let's say 2048(my packet size) bytes to some SAMPLE pointer, and then with that data pointer I'm going to be sending it across a socket)

Comment: @cooooookiemonster sorry there are not enough details in your question, could you ask a new stackoverflow question with more details on this new question?